# Obtaining ActiveRecords if NOT nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, null

I would like to be able to gather all records in a table where the user_id is not null.
This is what I have but it doesn't seem to be working (even though I've had it working in a seperate project):

```
named_scope :all_registered, :conditions => ["user_id != ?", nil]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

SQL has a specific operator to check for NULL: `IS NULL` and `IS NOT NULL`

```
named_scope :all_registered, :conditions => ["user_id IS NOT NULL"]
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
named_scope :all_registered, :conditions => "user_id IS NOT NULL"
```

Answer (score 0):

In Rails 4 you can use **NOT conditions**, see [Active Record Query Interface](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#not-conditions)

e.g:

```
User.where.not(id: nil)
```

or as a scope:

```
scope :all_registered, -> { where.not(user_id: nil) }
```